# How to create a .exe file in netbeans?

Tags: java, netbeans, jar, exe

I've created a project in netbeans and I want it to be runnable in another computer without having the netbeans installed (just like a `.exe` in visual basic).

I pressed <kbd>F11</kbd> and I got a `lib` folder which has a `.jar` file on it. But then I don't know how to work it out, which one do I have to double click?

Can anyone please guide me?

Answer (score 3):

If you created a java project, then the "other" computer should have the java runtime installed, in order for the jar to be executed there (java -jar your.jar) otherwise if you really want an .exe use one of the many jar2exe converters found on the almighty internet, such as http://www.ucware.com/jexec/index.htm

Answer (score 1):

To run jar file on other computer you should have at least jdk. Their is no need to install NetBeans but you have to first set database connectivity to pc and your database. After connectivity just double click on jar file your project will run.

To know how to create Jar file in NetBeans check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9681876/how-to-create-a-jar-file-in-netbeans) link.

Answer (score 0):

What type of project is this Desktop application OR Web based application ? If you are using java then for Desktop application you need to create a *.JAR and for Web based : *.WAR.

There are simple step to create jar/ war. please follow any tutorial.