# How to create a Jar file in Netbeans

Tags: netbeans, jar

Well I have my source code that i have done using the IDE netbeans. Now I wanted to move this java application to a web application. For that I need to create a jar file from my source code, so that I could invoke it in ma jsp file. 
I have not been able to find any option in netbeans or any other way to create a .jar file of this source code. 
Could someone tell me how to do that.

Thanks

Answer (score 131):

Create a Java archive (.jar) file using NetBeans as follows:

1. Right-click on the Project name
2. Select **Properties**
3. Click **Packaging**
4. Check **Build JAR after Compiling**
5. Check **Compress JAR File**
6. Click **OK** to accept changes
7. Right-click on a Project name
8. Select **Build** or **Clean and Build**

**Clean and Build** will first delete build artifacts (such as `.class` files), whereas **Build** will retain any existing `.class` files, creating new versions necessary. To elucidate, imagine a project with two classes, A and B.

When built the first time, the IDE creates `A.class` and `B.class`. Now you delete `B.java` but don't clear out `B.class`. Executing **Build** should leave `B.class` in the build directory, and bundle it into the JAR. Selecting **Clean and Build** will delete `B.class`. Since `B.java` was deleted, no longer will `B.class` be bundled.

The JAR file is built. To view it inside NetBeans:

1. Click the **Files** tab
2. Expand **Project name >> dist**

Ensure files aren't being excluded when building the JAR file.

Comment: Ensure files aren't being excluded when building the JAR file. HOW ?

Comment: Netbeans 12 doesn't have a "packaging" option in a project's property dialog.

Comment: @Tulains Córdova, agree, currently this answer is useless absolutely

Comment: NetBeansProjects/YourProjectName/dist. There will be jar file. NetBeans IDE 10.

Answer (score 10):

Please do right click on the project and go to properties.
Then go to Build and Packaging.
You can see the JAR file location that is produced by defualt setting of netbean in the dist directory.

Comment: hey bud the path displays 'dist/JavaApplication1.jar' but I cannot find that in my dist folder

Comment: In the Netbeans IDE you can't see all the files in the 'Projects' (only those the Netbeans programmers think you need for developing), however if you bring up the 'Files' tab you should be able to see all the project files.

Comment: Netbeans 12 doesn't have a "packaging" option in a project's property dialog.

Answer (score 8):

I also tried to make an executable jar file that I could run with the following command:

```
java -jar <jarfile>
```

After some searching I found the following link:

[Packaging and Deploying Desktop Java Applications](https://netbeans.org/kb/articles/javase-deploy.html)

I set the project's main class:

1. Right-click the project's node and choose Properties
2. Select the Run panel and enter the main class in the Main Class field
3. Click OK to close the Project Properties dialog box
4. Clean and build project

Then in the fodler dist the newly created jar should be executable with the command I mentioned above.

Comment: I'm not seeing a dist folder. Any steps or settings I'm missing?

Comment: Go to the where your NetBeans project is located in the file system. For the folder dist be there you must build or clean and build the project.

Comment: this is good explanation whereas people forget how to running jar file, but its not on the same context as OP asking for.

Answer (score 2):

Now (2020) NetBeans 11 does it automatically with the "Build" command (right click on the project's name and choose "Build")

Comment: And in version 12. Look in target folder after build. Many thanks seinecle.

Comment: No attriibute in the manifest file, cannot run with javac -jar