# java sqlite exception

Tags: java, sqlite, exception, jar, export

I made a Java application using netbeans and used sqlite as database
Everything works in netbeans but when i export the program to jar file and run it on another machine, an exception appeared when i try to connect sqlite database

The exception is about this line: Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC"); 
and the exception is: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.sqlite.JDBC

I looked at all related threads in stackoverflow and no pure answer about this.

Thanks in advanced,

Comment: You need to set the classpath and include all the Jar files you depend on.

Answer (score 0):

Just add the sqlite driver jar to your class path.
You application can't find the class `org.sqlite.JDBC` so it means a jar is missing in your class path.

Comment: how to add it? and when? before export to jar or after?

Answer (score 0):

Either include the sqlite jdbc driver in the jar file or make sure that you have it in your classpath. Add it as -classpath **sqlite driver**

Comment: `java -cp "sqlite driver JAr" -jar YOURJARHERE`

Comment: make sure the sqlite driver jar is in the same directory as your jar file or give the full path

Comment: when i execute that command it run the application and display the same exception !

Comment: Another option is to include in the jar itself. Look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9681876/how-to-create-a-jar-file-in-netbeans) how to do it in netbeans

Answer (score 0):

Problem Solved

I had import the sqlite jar file for both compile time and run time. From netbeans -> project properties -> Libraries.

and Then i moved the exported jar file from dist folder in addition to lib folder to another machine .. and worked smoothly .. Thanks Guys up