# How can you make a Java app executable?

Tags: java, bash, netbeans, jframe, executable

I have written a simple little program that opens a JFrame window every time you click a button. Although each time I want to run it I have to go into my IDE(NetBeans) and run it from there. Would I be able to make a .jar thing and it will run like that? How do you make it executable. Should I use a batch or bash file to run it?

Comment: See this: http://www.jwrapper.com/ - also this question has been answered many times on this website! Be sure to check and good luck!

Answer (score 3):

In Netbeans you can right click on your project in the Project Explorer and then select clean and build.

[image]

After that you can find the .jar under dist, which is located in your project folder.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You're looking to make a jar file. If you're on windows/x whatever graphical interface, you simply run it like any other executable. If not then you can run it from the command line like any other program.

To make a jar from the command line as per the Oracle documentation http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/build.html:

```
jar cf jar-file-name input-file(s)
```

NetBeans also has an interface to turn your project into a .jar if I recall correctly.

Edit: Yes it does have an interface. A quick search of the site yields:
[How to create a Jar file in Netbeans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9681876/how-to-create-a-jar-file-in-netbeans)