# Mac OS El Capitan never opens .jar files

Tags: java, macos, jar

Every time I try to save a.jar file for my programming course and it doesn't open, and yes I save the META.MF whit the correct path, I even stop making them on the Terminal and use Net Beans but same problem `Error: Could not find or load main class a3t8e1.A3T8e1` maybe I need to download something else.

I search on the internet and download the jar launcher but nothing better.

[image]
this is the .jar unpacked

Comment: What is the difference in the first A3T8e1 file and the one in the folder? Also, are you following the answer provided here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9681876/how-to-create-a-jar-file-in-netbeans

Answer (score 0):

Please try to right click the .jar file and click the **Get Info**. Under the **Open with**, select the *Jar Launcher.app*. After that, try to reopen your related .jar file.

Comment: the java launcher says it can't be open, that I should try on the terminal

Comment: well , in current directory you can type this command to terminal like : java -jar <jar file>