# How to generate unique jar file of project

Tags: java, jar, javafx-2, executable-jar

I have a project in Java FX. I use SQlite so I added the jar file for it, then, when I generate the jar of my application I get something like this:

```
|--dist
|----myapplication.jar
|----lib
|------sqlite.jar
```

So, what I want is to generate a unique jar file that contains my application and the sqlite.jar, which option do I have to do it? I'm using Netbeans 8.1. Thanks!

Comment: may can help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9681876/how-to-create-a-jar-file-in-netbeans