# Swing GUI usage on daily basis

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I am new to Java Swing. I just started to learn about Swing.
I see these tutorial videos to develop GUI for ones needs using Net-beans/Eclipse. My question might be simple/funny to most of you guys.

Lets say GUI is developed to do basic calculation like addition/multiplication and when the project is run on Eclipse/Net-beans its doing perfectly fine.

How do we bundle the code and give it to users so that they can the GUI to do any calculation?
Is it something that will be bundled as setup or exe file?
Basically, how do other use this UI?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I convert my Java program to an .exe file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/147181/how-can-i-convert-my-java-program-to-an-exe-file)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're looking for is called `Building` which creates a jar file (`.jar`) and contains intermediate code (bytecode) which allows users to run the code like an executable (`.exe`) file.

Remember: You'll need a place for the program to start from (you probably already have this if you can run the program from your IDE) (ie: `public static void main (String[] args) { ... }`)

---

Refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20786265/6945457) link for building in netbeans, and [this](http://help.eclipse.org/neon/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftasks-33.htm) one for building in eclipse.

Comment: Thank you!! that answers my question.