# illegal key size on executable jar

Tags: java, swing, encryption, netbeans

I am developing a simple java swing application which can encrypt/decrypt using AES-256 on NetBeans.

In development, there is an issue of illegal key size, which I need to install JCE unlimited strength .jar file. Once I did that everything worked fine.

Until, I exported an executable jar file when the error came back again!

> illegal key size.

What should I do ?

**Environment**

JAVA 1.8, JCE Installed, JAVA_HOME has been set, NetBeans IDE.

Comment: Sounds like you didn't export with the .jar file which fixed your problem.

Comment: I do it from this link http://stackoverflow.com/a/20786265/2077479

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java Security: Illegal key size or default parameters?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6481627/java-security-illegal-key-size-or-default-parameters)

Comment: currently I run from terminal.. java -jar "/Users/Activity/NetBeansProjects/xxxAuth/dist/xxxAuth.jar" and it work

Comment: but open by double click not work, any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

For me both terminal and sh file execution will cause the exception while running in IDEA works fine.

After checking my `Java` folder,I found that  there was folders naming `jdk1.8.0_121` (whick contains 'jre') and `jre1.8.0_131`.And `java -version` indicated my java version was `1.8.0_131`.

So I guess maybe my `jre` updated sometime while `jdk` remains the same.After update the new `jre`'s `lib/security` following [instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6481627/java-security-illegal-key-size-or-default-parameters).Then everything works fine.

I think the reason why editors like IDEA and terminals have different running behavior is: the former works through compiler(`jdk`)  while the latter through runtime(`jre`).