# Am I able to run a java program without the need for a code editor environment?

Tags: java, netbeans, export, desktop

I am aiming to create an EPoS-esque system and was wondering if there was anyway that I could export the code and be able to run it outside of a program like NetBeans (the IDE i will be using to code the program), and on its own separate software?

For example having its own desktop icon that would automatically run the interface i have designed outside of NetBeans.

Comment: It's not only possible, it's the natural order of things.  You don't think that people deploy code to production in NetBeans, do you?

Comment: @duffymo Obviously not just wasn't sure on ways of going around it so just phrased it like so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a JAR file and run it from outside Netbeans. You need to install JRE/JDK in the machine you are willing to run the application on.

For instructions check here: [How to create a Jar file in Netbeans](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9681876/5137352)