# creating jar file for java appication using derby database

Tags: java, netbeans, jar, derby

I have recently developed a school management system in java netbeans using derby(java built in database).Now i want to make a jar file and proivide it to my client .So can this jar run on client pc without netbeans or java installed? and what about database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java must be installed with at least the version of java you used. Embedded databases need no extra installation other than in your code.

Starting from a jar is a bit different than in the IDE from a class path. A jar contains only read-only resources, and the file names in the jar (zip archive) are case-sensitive.

It could be that the software first has to use a resource file as initial template to be copied to the file system. Like a prefilled database to be written to.

- Java 9 can use `jlink` to create your own smaller JRE, java run time. (I do not think you are using java 9 though.)
- Java 8 has a [javapackager](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/javapackager.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can create a jar of your source code using netbeans using [How to create a Jar file in Netbeans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9681876/how-to-create-a-jar-file-in-netbeans)
You cannot package the derby or what ever database into a jar. Instead you can have script to start the db.