# Generate .JAR file using NetBeans 11.0

Tags: java, netbeans, jar, executable-jar, netbeans-11

I'm trying to generate the (**.JAR**) file using **NetBeans 11.0**, I have followed some answers like [How to create a Jar file in Netbeans](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20786265/7954210) but I don't find the Packaging under Build, Also I tried to **Clean & Build Project** but I can't find `/dist` folder.

Can anyone help me

LOG :

```
Scanning for projects...

------------------------------------------------------------------------
Building FlickerURLMaker 1.0-SNAPSHOT
------------------------------------------------------------------------

--- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ FlickerURLMaker ---
Deleting C:\Users\USER\Documents\NetBeansProjects\FlickerURLMaker\target

--- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ FlickerURLMaker ---
Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Users\USER\Documents\NetBeansProjects\FlickerURLMaker\src\main\resources

--- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ FlickerURLMaker ---
Changes detected - recompiling the module!
Compiling 2 source files to C:\Users\USER\Documents\NetBeansProjects\FlickerURLMaker\target\classes

--- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ FlickerURLMaker ---
Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Users\USER\Documents\NetBeansProjects\FlickerURLMaker\src\test\resources

--- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ FlickerURLMaker ---
Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date

--- maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) @ FlickerURLMaker ---
No tests to run.

--- maven-jar-plugin:2.4:jar (default-jar) @ FlickerURLMaker ---
Building jar: C:\Users\USER\Documents\NetBeansProjects\FlickerURLMaker\target\FlickerURLMaker-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar

--- maven-install-plugin:2.4:install (default-install) @ FlickerURLMaker ---
Installing C:\Users\USER\Documents\NetBeansProjects\FlickerURLMaker\target\FlickerURLMaker-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar to C:\Users\USER\.m2\repository\maa\FlickerURLMaker\1.0-SNAPSHOT\FlickerURLMaker-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
Installing C:\Users\USER\Documents\NetBeansProjects\FlickerURLMaker\pom.xml to C:\Users\USER\.m2\repository\maa\FlickerURLMaker\1.0-SNAPSHOT\FlickerURLMaker-1.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
------------------------------------------------------------------------
BUILD SUCCESS
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total time: 2.613 s
Finished at: 2019-06-26T10:26:33+01:00
Final Memory: 16M/170M
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

POM.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>maa</groupId>
    <artifactId>FlickerURLMaker</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
</project>
```

[image]

STRUCTURE :

[image]

Comment: share console log................dist file location show on there....

Comment: @panthaistiaque please see my update post

Comment: Do you see any folder named `target`?

Comment: @Hasitha M Jayawardana, I found .jar file but when I click on it, it does not work, nothing happened

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I see this is a `maven` project. In maven projects, the build jar file will be in the `target` folder. But if you use any dependencies it will not attach them to that build `jar` automatically. You need to add the following code to the `pom.xml` file.

```
<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
  <configuration>
    <archive>
      <manifest>
        <mainClass>fully.qualified.MainClass</mainClass>
      </manifest>
    </archive>
    <descriptorRefs>
      <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
    </descriptorRefs>
  </configuration>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>make-assembly</id> <!-- this is used for inheritance merges -->
      <phase>package</phase> <!-- bind to the packaging phase -->
      <goals>
        <goal>single</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

Commonly this goal is tied to a build phase to execute automatically. So when you build your project, at that time your `fat.jar` file will be available in your target folder.

So in your case your `pom.xml` file should be like this,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>maa</groupId>
    <artifactId>FlickerURLMaker</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>maa.flickerurlmaker.URLMaker</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>make-assembly</id> <!-- this is used for inheritance merges -->
                        <phase>package</phase> <!-- bind to the packaging phase -->
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, should I replace the previous code by yours or just add it

Comment: No, you can add these lines below. Can you post your `pom.xml` file? So I can help you.

Comment: I have added it

Comment: And make sure to replace your `main class` with this `fully.qualified.MainClass`

Comment: Unfortunately doesn't work, when I Go to `C:\Users\USER\Documents\NetBeansProjects\FlickerURLMaker\target` I found two files **.JAR**, no one of them want to open, I just want an executable JAR of my simple project

Comment: Did you add the `main class` to `pom.xml` file?

Comment: Can you please explain more, Because it's my first time with Netbeans, I have worked with Android Studio it's a little confusing

Comment: Can you post your project structure?

Comment: Check my new answer with `<mainClass>maa.flickerurlmaker.URLMaker</mainClass>`

Comment: Pleased to know it helped :)

Comment: An ultimate guide how to make fat jar in Netbeans maven project. Thank you.