# JavaFX application to windows exe on Mac OSX

Tags: macos, javafx, netbeans, exe

I am working on a project using Netbeans to create a JavaFX application. I need to deploy the application on both platforms (**Mac and Windows**).

I am using a mac and I can create the .dmg file using the native packaging in Netbeans.

My question is, How can I create a .exe file (for Windows) using Netbeans on mac? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I found your answer

source : [How to create a .exe file in netbeans?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5402247/how-to-create-a-exe-file-in-netbeans#5402307)

"If you created a java project, then the "other" computer should have the java runtime installed, in order for the jar to be executed there (java -jar your.jar) otherwise if you really want an .exe use one of the many jar2exe converters found on the almighty internet, such as http://www.ucware.com/jexec/index.htm"